# how to pass LPTSTR to a function and modify it's contents

Tags: c++

I need a function that is supplied a LPTSTR and an enumerated value, constructs a string based on the value and puts it in the LPTSTR.

I've written the following function which uses an array of names indexed by an enumerated value:

```
bool GetWinClassName(const int &WinType, LPTSTR *className, const int bufSize)
{
    bool allOk = true;
    LPTSTR tempName = new TCHAR[bufSize];
    _stprintf_s(tempName, bufSize, TEXT("Win%sClass"), g_WinNames[WinType]);
    std::cout << (char*)tempName << std::endl;
    if (FAILED(StringCchCopy(*className, (bufSize+1)*sizeof(TCHAR), tempName)))
    {
        allOk = false;
    }
    delete[] tempName;
    return allOk;
}
```

(Originally I just had the `_stprintf_s` line using `className` instead of `tempName`, this has been broken up to find where the error lies.)

The above code compiles in VC2010 Express but gives an unhandled exception: "Access violation writing" to (presumably) `*className` when it tries to execute the `StringCchCopy` line.

I can get this to work by doing

```
className = new TCHAR[bufSize];
```

before calling the function (with a matching  `delete[]` after it) but do I really need to do that each time I want to call the function?

I understand *where* the problem lies but not *why* which is hampering my efforts to come up with a workable solution. The problem appears to me to be that I can't put something in the LPTSTR (via `_stprintf_s` or `StringCchCopy`) unless I allocate it some memory by using `new TCHAR[bufSize]`. I've tried assigning it an intial value of exactly the same size but with the same results which is leading me to think that the memory allocation actually has nothing to do with it. Is it then somehow casting my LPTSTR into a TCHAR[]? I don't see how that's possible but at this stage, I'd believe anything.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? (Or at least where my understanding is wrong.) And a probably related question is why is my `std::cout` only showing the first character of the string?

Comment: "I need a function that is supplied a LPTSTR", jeez, you *need* to support Windows 9x? why on earth do you need that, if I may ask? by the way, what you're doing wrong: (1) supporting Windows 9x is *probably* wrong, unless you really need it (if you do then please explain why), (2) programming in C when you're using C++

Comment: The fact that you needed a cast to make the code "work" should be a clear giveaway what's wrong with the `cout` line. You're asking the compiler to treat something that doesn't point to a C-style string as if it did. (You pointed out that it's printing the wrong number of characters? Think about it -- how were you expecting it to know how many to print?)

Answer (score 1):

```
wstring winClassName( int const winType )
{
    return wstring( L"Win" ) + g_WinNames[winType] + L"Class";
}
```

But I'm just completely baffled why you have that global array of names etc.: it's probably a design level error.

Answer (score 0):

> do I really need to do that each time I want to call the function?

An LPTSTR value is not a string object, it is simply a pointer-to-TCHAR. If you do not allocate a buffer, where do you think the characters will go? You must make sure that the `className` pointer argument points to a memory buffer that you can write to. Whether you allocate a new buffer each time is up to you.

As Alf implies, a better alternative is to avoid the direct use of pointers and dynamically allocated arrays altogether, and return a string object.

> why is my std::cout only showing the first character of the string?

Use std::wcout instead if UNICODE is defined.